# Running genhtml using cygwin Perl.exe in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, cygwin, code-coverage, lcov

I'm trying to run genhtml using perl.exe from Cygwin in Windows.

I have installed cygwin and placed genhtml in the bin directory of cygwin.  I went to that directory and used the command line in Windows:

```
perl genhtml abc.dat
```

where abc.dat is the name of the lcov file for genhtml.

However I got an error saying:

```
Reading data file abc.dat
genhtml: ERROR: cannot read file abc.dat!
```

I tried even with a blank file, but the same error returned.  How do I get around this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I do need to go to cygwin and run chmod 777 in the locationm of the .dat file in order to be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Is abc.dat in the cygwin/bin directory?  If not genhtml won't find it unless you specify the full path.

Comment: Yes it is.  I putted the dat file in the bin directory for simplicity's sake.  I have a feeling that it might have something to do with linux permission setting, but I'm running under Windows so I doubt this is the case. Having said that, I'm not a linux person so I could be very wrong.